# Deallocation of object

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have an object which inherits from the MKPlacemark class of MapKit. I have a method launch during viewDidLoad of my ViewController that creates such object (alloc + init) and pass it to a MapView as follows

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:<my instance of my class inheriting MKPlacemark>]
```

However, when I launch my program, I get the following error message:

```
An instance 0x9a5d650 of class <name of my class> was deallocated while key value   
observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even 
become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on 
NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger.
```

Note that I use ARC. Can anyone tell me how can I avoid such deallocation?

Thanks !

EDIT: My problem is not the warning in itself, it is that I do not want this object to be deallocate at that moment...

EDIT2: The code of the class is the following

The .h file looks like this

```
@interface OPTCreatureMark : MyMark

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate; 
@end
```

and the .m like that

```
@implementation MyMark

@synthesize coordinate;

-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate_ {
    if (self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate_ addressDictionary:nil]) {

        self.coordinate=coordinate_;

        return self;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you using KVO here in any of your class?

Comment: Which class was deallocated? The view controller on screen? The view on screen? A model in that controller? A model used by another controller? This warning means that you forgot to `removeObserver:forKeyPath:` somewhere.

Comment: It is my class inheriting MKPlacemark.

Comment: Can you provide the code to your `MKPlacemark`-conforming class?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are presumably adding an observer to these Placemarks?

Comment: Hi, I posted some code in the edit no 2. :)

Comment: According to addNotation method documentation, mapView retains the specified object. That means, your object should always have a pointer and should not be deallocated, unless your self.mapView itself is getting deallocated. Can you verify that? You said you calling this in viewDidLoad of your ViewController, override dealloc method of your viewController and put an NSLog statement in there to verify if you view controller is getting deallocated or not.

Comment: Right before the addAnnotation line, please NSLog the coordinates of the annotation being added.  Make sure the latitude is between -90 and +90 and that the longitude is between -180 and +180.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed using KVO, it sounds like you need to remove the observer in your object's `dealloc` method like so:

```
[self removeObserver:self.myDelegate forKeyPath:@"zoom"];
```

Otherwise messages could be sent to a deallocated instance of your class (which can no longer respond because it's been deallocated), thus causing an exception.

Comment: I'd suggest doing that prior to dealloc.  During dealloc, the object graph will be in an incoherent state.   If that observer files during object graph tear down, bad things might happen.